# Getting time from ntp server without allowing the user to manipulate the time

Tags: android, date, ntp

I am trying to get the time from the NTP server. I have a method that it is asking multiple servers for getting the time (if the first one gives a result the other won't be asked they are for backup). In order to resolve the date from the InetAddress I am using TimeInfo from the library: commons-net:commons-net:3.0.1. This resolved the time as it should but it becomes an issue when I will change the time on the phone manually. If I set the time to 1/2/2019 this NTPUDPClient when converting the date it will give this date instead of the actual 1/29/2019. I want to convert this time to the actual date even when the user will change the time on the phone.

Tried searching for how this InetAddress to be resolved with some other component but couldn't find anything.

```
public Date getCurrentTimeFromNtpServer() {
    Date result = null;
    NTPUDPClient client = new NTPUDPClient();

    client.setDefaultTimeout(2000);
    for (String host : NTP_SERVERS) {
        try {
            InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            TimeInfo timeInfo = client.getTime(inetAddress);
            result = DateUtil.toUtc(new Date(timeInfo.getReturnTime()));
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, "Failed to get current time MTP", e);
        }
    }
    client.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What I have discovered when opened the NTPUDPClient is that in the method is creating an TimeStamp object:   TimeStamp now = TimeStamp.getCurrentTime();   and he is using that time as a result. I really have no idea why should I ask this server when in the end the result is the time from the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the answer. Too many examples on the internet which are not correct. What it should be done is:

```
public Date getCurrentTimeFromNtpServer() {

    Date result = null;
    final NTPUDPClient client = new NTPUDPClient();
    client.setDefaultTimeout(2000);
    for (final String host : NTP_SERVERS) {
        try {
            final InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            final TimeInfo timeInfo = client.getTime(inetAddress);
            final Long time = timeInfo.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime();
            result = DateUtil.toUtc(time);
            SystemUtil.sleep(500);
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, "Failed to get current time NTP", e);
        }
    }
    client.close();
    return result;
}
```

This will give the actual time instead of the one that it is created in the NTPUDPClient and it is the phone time.